# Xmonad how to prevent floating window from staying always on top?

Tags: haskell, xmonad

This is my layout config:

```hs
mySpacing :: Integer -> l a -> XMonad.Layout.LayoutModifier.ModifiedLayout Spacing l a
mySpacing i = spacingRaw False (Border i i i i) True (Border i i i i) True

tiled    =   renamed [Replace "tiled"]
           $ smartBorders
           $ limitWindows 12
           $ mySpacing 5
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []
full    =    renamed [Replace "full"]
           $ noBorders
           $ Full
magnify  =   renamed [Replace "magnify"]
           $ magnifier
           $ limitWindows 4
           $ mySpacing 5
           $ ResizableTall 1 (3/100) (1/2) []

myLayout = T.toggleLayouts full $ desktopLayoutModifiers $ onWorkspaces ["7"] magnify $ myDefaultLayout
  where
    myDefaultLayout = tiled
                  ||| magnify
```

How to prevent floating window from always staying on top and rather hide below the active window on a workspace?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer to the question as asked is that it can't be done from outside the xmonad library. xmonad has a deeply-baked assumption that all floating windows should appear above any tiled window.

If you don't ever need to resize your floating windows, you could consider playing with [SimplestFloat](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-SimplestFloat.html), [LayoutCombinators](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-contrib-0.16/docs/XMonad-Layout-LayoutCombinators.html), and [sending messages](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Operations.html#v:sendMessage) in your [`manageHook`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xmonad-0.15/docs/XMonad-Core.html#v:manageHook), but I suspect it's going to be more trouble than it's worth.

Otherwise your only recourse is grabbing a copy of the xmonad source and modifying it.